# Why does collection show as blank in console, but available in Meteor server?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, console

I create a function that creates a whole bunch of tasks and it prints them all out out in the server function and displays on the server log. When I run Tasks.find().fetch() in the console, it returns a blank array. What am I doing wrong here? I have a few other objects that appear to be set up the same way and DO show in the console.

```
let createDummyTasks = function(){
    var numberToFake=1000;
    var equipment = ["Auto Folding Machine", "Binding Machine", 
                    "Scissor Machine", "Folding Machine",
                    "Cutting Machine"];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberToFake; i++) {
        createDummyTask();
    }
    console.log(Tasks.find().fetch())

    function createDummyTask(){
        let name = faker.name.jobArea();
        let status = randomStatus();
        let duration = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) + 1;      
        let startDate = faker.date.between('2017-09-10', '2017-09-17');
        let endDate = faker.date.between('2017-09-18', '2017-09-30');
        let equipment = Equipment.aggregate({$sample: {size: 1}});
        // let thisEquipment = equipment[Math.floor(Math.random() * equipment.length)]

        Tasks.insert({name: name, 
                    status: status,
                    duration: duration,
                    startDate: startDate,
                    endDate: endDate
                    }, function(error){
                        if(error){
                            console.log("error");
                        } else {
                            console.log("success");
                        }
                    })

    }

}
```

In 'collections' folder off of app root I have a task.js

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Tasks.allow({
  insert() {
    // When we will ALLOW inserts on the client.
    return false;
  },
  update() {
    // When we will ALLOW updates on the client.
    return false;
  },
  remove() {
    // When we will ALLOW removes on the client.
    return false;
  }
});

Tasks.deny({
  insert() {
    // When we will DENY inserts on the client.
    return true;
  },
  update() {
    // When we will DENY updates on the client.
    return true;
  },
  remove() {
    // When we will DENY removes on the client.
    return true;
  }
});
```

and then I subscribe to the items on the client js

```
// *************************************************************
Template.schedule.onCreated( () => {
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'customers' );
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'jobs' ); 
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'tasks' ); 
  Template.instance().subscribe( 'equipment' ); 

});

Template.widget.onRendered(function(){
    if(Meteor.isDevelopment){
        Meteor.call('populateDummyInfo', (error)=>{
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you add the code where you publish the collection with `Meteor.publish()` ?

Comment: Make sure the `schema` and `publication` files are properly imported to the `main.js` of server

Answer (score 0):

I didn't publish....

```
Meteor.publish('tasks', function () {
  return Tasks.find();
});
```